# Prove that $M_i \leq M_i'M_i''$ and $m_i \geq m_i'm_i''$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$ and $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Let $M_i'$ and $m_i'$ denote the appropriate $\sup$'s and $\inf$'s for $f$. Define $M_i''$ and $m_i''$ similarly for $g$, and $M_i$ and $m_i$ similarly for $fg$. Prove that $M_i \leq M_i'M_i''$ and $m_i \geq m_i'm_i''$.

To prove the first inequality, i.e. $M_i \leq M_i'M_i''$, we note that this is equivalent to $$\sup{fg} \geq \sup{f}\sup{g}.$$ I am not sure how to prove this statement, but I think using the fact that $g(x) \geq 0$ will help. Similarly with the second statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only true if $f(x) \geqslant 0$ as well.

For example, if $-4 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant -2$ and $1 \leqslant g(x) \leqslant 3,$ then $-12 \leqslant f(x)g(x) \leqslant-2.$ In this case $M_i \leqslant M_i'm_i''$ and $m_i \geqslant m_i'M_i''.$

Consider some subinterval $I_i$.

For all $x \in I_i$ we have

$$f(x) \leqslant \sup_{x \in I_i}f(x) = M_i', \\ 0 \leqslant g(x) \leqslant \sup_{x \in I_i}g(x) = M_i''.$$

Hence, since $M_i''\geqslant 0$ and $M_i'' = 0$ if and only if $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in I_i,$ we have

$$f(x)g(x) \leqslant M_i'M_i''.$$

As you observed, we need $g(x) \geqslant  0$ to ensure that the inequality is not reversed upon multiplication by $g(x)$ and $M_i''$.

Since $M_i'M_i''$ is an upper bound for $f(x)g(x)$ on $I_i$ it must be no smaller than the supremum (least upper bound).

Therefore,

$$M_i = \sup_{x \in I_i}f(x)g(x) \leqslant M_i'M_i''.$$

Proving $m_i \geqslant m_i'm_i''$ is carried out in a similar way. It would be a good exercise for you to attempt this yourself. The hypothesis that $g(x) \geqslant 0$ will again be necessary. Since $0$ is a lower bound we can argue that the infimum (greatest lower bound) must be no smaller than $0$, that is $m_i'' \geqslant 0$, and multiplying by $g(x)$ and $m_i''$ does not reverse an inequality.

Comment: If $|f(x)|,|g(x)| \leq M$ for $x$ in $[a,b]$, show that $$U(fg,\mathcal{P})-L(fg,\mathcal{P}) \leq M \left\{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n [M_i'-m_i'](t_i-t_{i-1})+\sum_{i=1}^n[M_i''-m_i''](t_i-t_{i-1}) \right\}.$$

Comment: Yep, your answer helped.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the inequalities because I don't see how that example disproves it.

Comment: You really need both $f$ and $g$ to be non-negative to ensure $\sup fg \leqslant (\sup f)(\sup g).$  In my example, $f$ ranges between -4 and -2  and $g$ ranges between 1 and 3.  The largest possible value that the product $fg$ can reach is -2. This is possible if at the same point $x$ we have $f(x) = -2$ and $g(x) = 1$.  Hence, $\sup fg = -2 > (\sup f)(\sup g) = (-2)(3) = -6.$

Comment: There must be an error in the problem then. What about the other problem I asked above? Can you tell me how to solve it?