# Prove the upper and lower sum inequality

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$ and $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Let $M_i'$ and $m_i'$ denote the appropriate $\sup$'s and $\inf$'s for $f$. Define $M_i''$ and $m_i''$ similarly for $g$, and $M_i$ and $m_i$ similarly for $fg$. Prove that 
>   if $|f(x)|,|g(x)| \leq M$ for $x$ in $[a,b]$, then $$U(fg,\mathcal{P})-L(fg,\mathcal{P}) \leq M \left\{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n [M_i'-m_i'](t_i-t_{i-1})+\sum_{i=1}^n[M_i''-m_i''](t_i-t_{i-1}) \right\}.$$

We will need [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772080/prove-that-m-i-leq-m-im-i-and-m-i-geq-m-im-i) question in order to answer this question. I don't see how to simplify this relationship more into something manageable using $$U(fg,\mathcal{P})-L(fg,\mathcal{P}) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n [M_i'M_i''-m_i'm_i''](t_i-t_{i-1})$$ which follows as an immediate corollary of the question cited. We will need to incorporate this somehow.

Comment: Could you provide the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We have $0 \leqslant |f(x)|,|g(x)| \leqslant M$ for all $x \in [a,b].$

Using the triangle inequality,

$$\begin{align}|f(x)g(x) - f(y)g(y)| &= |f(x)g(x) - f(x)g(y) + f(x)g(y) - f(y)g(y)| \\ &\leqslant |f(x)||g(x) - g(y)| + |g(y)||f(x) - f(y)|\\ &\leqslant
M|f(x) - f(y)| + M|g(x)-g(y)|.\end{align}$$

Note that for any partition subinterval $I_i,$

$$M_i - m_i = \sup_{x \in I_i} f(x)g(x)- \inf_{x \in I_i} f(x)g(x) =  \sup_{x,y \in I_i}|f(x)g(x) - f(y)g(y)| \\ M_i' - m_i' = \sup_{x \in I_i} f(x)- \inf_{x \in I_i} f(x) =  \sup_{x,y \in I_i}|f(x) - f(y)|  \\ M_i'' - m_i'' = \sup_{x \in I_i} g(x)- \inf_{x \in I_i} g(x) =  \sup_{x,y \in I_i}|g(x) - g(y)|  . $$

Hence,

$$\begin{align}M_i - m_i &= \sup_{x,y \in I_i}|f(x)g(x) - f(y)g(y)| \\ &\leqslant M\sup_{x,y \in I_i}|f(x) - f(y)| + M\sup_{x,y \in I_i}|g(x) - g(y)| \\ &= M(M_i'-m_i') + M(M_i'' - m_i''),\end{align}$$

where we have applied the inequality (supremum of sum bounded above  by sum of suprema)

$$\sup_{x,y}[h_1(x,y) + h_2(x,y)] \leqslant \sup_{x,y}h_1(x,y) + \sup_{x,y}h_2(x,y).$$

The result,

$$M_i - m_i \leqslant M(M_i'-m_i') + M(M_i'' - m_i''),$$

yields the desired inequality for upper/lower sums.